# Using Opacity of a Div without affecting The color of the Paragraph inside the Div

Tags: css, html

I have created a `div` with background color black, and written a `p` inside it with white. When I am using opacity in the `div`, the color of the `p` is also getting changed into gray. Is there any way to change the opacity only of the `div` without affecting the color of the `p`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on StackOverflow

Answer (score 2):

Just read this article. It explains everything: https://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/

You should have:

```
div {
     background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
     color: #fff; 
}
```

There are also same or similar questions here, like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15449280/html-css-text-background-transparent-but-text-not

Comment: I have tried with Rgba(0,0,0,.6) it is working perfect. But I have to use Opacity. Is there any way to do that using opacity?

Comment: There is a thread with your question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13248289/css-setting-background-opacity-without-rgba.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css :after selector to give shadow dom element the background color and opacity. This will not effect to p tag.
Here is jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vjandrei/fyvc3ejy/2/